# Need Help Finding a Function that Limits at a certain number

Tags: calculus, limits

In High School, a teacher of mine showed us a function that as it approached infinity, it would hit a certain specified number. This function would really help me with a function I am trying to design for an experience system in a software project, however, I'm having trouble remembering the specifics of this function.

If I remember correctly, it had to do with the properties of adding some sort of fraction where $\frac{x}{\text{some number}}$ to a larger fraction. My goal is to set the limit at some arbitrary number, and in a somewhat logarithmic way, approach the arbitrary number, but not exceed it.

My question is, what is the best way to design a function that has these properties, or is there an existing well-known function that has these properties?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but, do you mean $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{3x}{2x}}=\frac{3}{2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M>0$ be the number you want to hit. Then, one could take
$$f(x)=\frac{M}{1+e^{-x}}.$$

Comment: Is there any way to get the Y-intercept to be 0 with this function? Otherwise, this is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: No, but you can take $N>0$ to be a second number (still take $M>0$ the number you want to hit) and then take the function $f(x)=\frac{M+N}{1+e^{-x}}-N$. Then, the function approaches $-N$ if $x\to-\infty$, and $M$ if $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Then, the function also has a $Y$-intercept, namely at $x=\ln(N)-\ln(M)$.

Comment: Fun fact, selecting the same number for both M and N makes this function's Y intercept 0, which works exactly as intended ($x < 0$ is undefined in the context of the application of this function)

Comment: If you wish to make the graph of the function 'sharper' (in the sense of, increasing faster as $x$ increases) you can replace the $e^{-x}$ by $e^{-Kx}$ for a big number $K>0$. This will change the $X$-location of the $Y$-intercept to $x=(\ln(N)-\ln(M))/K$.

Comment: I used $e^{\frac{-x}{100}}$ to lower the speed at which a player can hit the limit!